# Javascript Dynamic Breadcrumbs - Client Side

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, client-side, breadcrumbs

Hello I am trying to implement dynamic Javascript breadcrumbs entirely client side.

I have been restricted from using server side languages for various reasons.

I have made some progress using these two threads:

1) [jQuery generate breadcrumbs from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445240/jquery-generate-breadcrumbs-from-url?rq=1)

2) [Approaches to build breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792114/approaches-to-build-breadcrumbs)

However I am still unable to successfully apply this code I am not used to working with Javascript and as such my experience is a limitation so please consider that in solutions.

Cheers.

This is what I have tried:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#breadcrumb", function breadCrumb(){

var here = location.href.split('/').slice(3);

var parts = [{ "text": 'Home', "link": '/' }];

for( var i = 0; i < here.length; i++ )
{
    var part = here[i];
    var text = part.toUpperCase();
    var link = '/' + here.slice( 0, i + 1 ).join('/');
    parts.push({ "text": text, "link": link });
}
});
```

I do not know how to convert back to HTML and put onto webpage.

This is what I am asking for help with.

Comment: I would consider using http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: What exact code have you tried and what exact problems did you have with it and what exactly are you asking for help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you out

```
document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML = '<span>' + part[i] + '</span>';
```

Where the ID is above replace with a ID of a element within your rendered page.
Ie: something along the lines of

```
<div id='breadcrumbs'></div>
```